# jsTree - Closing nodes on a specific level

Tags: javascript, jquery, jstree

I have a jstree with 5 levels of nodes.  I want to iterate through all nodes to close those nodes for which the level is 4 so that one doesn't see level 5 unless 4 is clicked to expand.  If there is a better approach than iterating, I'm all ears!

```
$("#mytree").bind('ready.jstree', function(event, data) {
  var $tree = $(this);
  $($tree.jstree().get_json($tree, {
    flat: true
  }))
  .each(function(index, value) {
     var node = $("#mytree").jstree().get_node(this.id);
     var lvl = node.parents.length;
     if (lvl = 4) {
       node.close_node(this, true);
     }    
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer, in case anyone else is looking to do the same.

Instead of opening all and then closing some, I started with all closed and opened the ones I wanted:

```
$("#mytree").bind('ready.jstree', function(event, data) {
   var $tree = $(this);
   $($tree.jstree().get_json($tree, {
    flat: true
   }))
  .each(function(index, value) {
     var node = $("#mytree").jstree().get_node(this.id);
     var lvl = node.parents.length;
     if (lvl <= 3) {
        $('#mytree').jstree().open_node({"id":node.id});
     }    
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to open the nodes of first level, you may try this.

```
           $('#myTree li').each( function() {
           var node=$("#myTree").jstree().get_node(this.id);
           var level = node.parents.length;
             if(level<=1){                  
             $('#myTree').jstree().open_node({"id":node.id});
             }
           });
```

It works for me, when I want to display the folders of an azure container. In my case, container is the root node.